Dual LP: Show that l1 regularization term is equivalent to equality constraint.

Consider the primal and dual formulation of a linear optimization problem:
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{split}
    \text{maximize} \quad & {\langle \vec{b}, \vec{z} \rangle} \\
    \text{subject to} \quad & A^T \vec{z} \le \vec{c} \\
  \end{split}
  \quad
  \Longleftrightarrow
  \quad
  \begin{split}
    \text{minimize} \quad & {\langle \vec{c}, \vec{x} \rangle} \\
    \text{subject to} \quad 
    & A \vec{x} = \vec{b} \\
    & \vec{x} \ge \vec{0} \\
  \end{split}
\end{gather*}
Suppose the feasible set of the primal form is nonempty and bounded, with ${\lVert \vec{z} \rVert}_\infty < \mu$ for all feasible $\vec{z}$. Consider a similar problem with a $L_1$ regularization term:
\begin{align*}
  \text{minimize} \quad & {\langle \vec{c}, \vec{y} \rangle} + \mu {\lVert A \vec{y} - \vec{b} \rVert}_1 \\
  \text{subject to} \quad & \vec{y} \ge \vec{0} \\
\end{align*}
Show that any solution $\vec{y}^*$ to the optimization problem with the regularization term is also a solution $\vec{x}^* = \vec{y}^*$ to the dual form of the original problem.

My work: First note that it would be sufficient to show that for any solution $\vec{y}^*$ that $A \vec{y}^* = \vec{b}$ so that $\vec{y}^*$ would also be a solution $\vec{x}^*$ to the dual form of the original problem.
Since the feasible set of the primal form of the original problem is nonempty and bounded there is some optimal solution $\vec{z}^*$. Due to strong duality there exists some solution to the dual problem $\vec{x}^*$ such that:
\begin{gather*}
  {\langle \vec{b}, \vec{z}^* \rangle} = {\langle \vec{c}, \vec{x}^* \rangle} \\
\end{gather*}
Due to feasibility of $\vec{z}^*$ we have:
\begin{gather*}
  {\lVert \vec{z}^* \rVert}_\infty < \mu, \quad
  A^T \vec{z}^* \le \vec{c} \\
\end{gather*}
Where can I go from here? I presume I need to use ${\lVert \vec{z}^* \rVert}_\infty < \mu$ some how.

This looks like a homework, so I am only going to point what I would have tried (I didn't do anything). As you already noticed, if you manage to prove that the solution $y^$ is such that $Ay^=b$, you are done. To do that, I would have tried to add $|z|_\infty \leq \mu$ to the primal. This does not change the solution and can be converted into classical linear constraints: $\forall i, |z_i|\leq \mu$. Then see what the dual looks like and see if $\mu | Ay-b |_1$ appears in some way.
